# How to include metadata/tags in gstreamer's RTSP streaming

Tags: metadata, gstreamer, rtsp

I want to insert metadata in RTSP streaming specifically in RTSP server. How exactly I can do that? My gstreamer pipeline is

```
"v4l2src  device=/dev/video3 ! videoconvert ! v4l2h264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0"
```

I want to insert a string of user defined data in RTSP stream. I tried an element called ***taginject*** but its of no use.
I tried passing this pipeline to ***gst_bin_iterate_all_by_interface()*** API which returns those elements which support ***GstTagSetter*** interface. But none of the elements in my pipeline support ***GstTagSetter*** interface. I tried using ***mux*** elements but those mux can not be linked to ***rtph264pay***. I can't use any other encoding other than H.264.
Please suggest any other methods to insert metadata.

Thanks